# What is the difference between using df.as[T] and df.asInstanceOf[Dataset[T]]?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

As mentioned in the title, what is the main difference between using `df.as[T]` and `df.asInstanceOf[Dataset[T]]`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, `asInstanceOf` is just telling the compiler to shut up and believe you that `df` is an instance of the `Dataset` class *(the T part is irrelevant due to type-erasure)*. In runtime, if the value is not an instance of that class you will get an exception; and in this case it will never be.

On the other hand, [`as` is a method defined in the Dataset class, which asks for an implicit **Encoder**](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#as%5BU%5D(implicitevidence$2:org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder%5BU%5D):org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset%5BU%5D) so it can *safely* cast the data; note that since the data is processed in runtime, the conversion may still fail.

So the difference is big and you should not use the former.

Comment: What do you men by safely cast?

Comment: @GYBE A `Dataset` is a distributed data structure, at runtime, the data is stored in a binary format optimized for **Spark** operations. An `Encoder` is a class that knows how to transform that binary format into / from **Scala** types like `Int`, `List` or **case classes**. That is what I mean with a _"safely cast"_, since `df.as[A]` will try to transform that `DataFrame` into a `Dataset[A]`; but remember it may still fail if, for example, the binary data represented a **String** and you tried to read it as a **Int**.